# php make directory with write permission not working

Tags: php, prestashop

In php I want to make a directory with write permission(0777). My php code looks like this

```
public function getContent()
  {
    global $cookie;
    $uploaddir = (dirname(__FILE__).'/storename');
    $tmpname = $uploaddir.'/';
    if(file_exists($uploaddir)){
      echo 'file exists';
    }
    else {
      mkdir($uploaddir,0777);
    }
  }
```

But here I am getting error `Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied on line 10` .  . So can someone kindly tell me why this error is coming out here? I am using LAMP server.

Comment: try chmod on the dir... like this but better... sudo chmod 777 -R www/

Comment: Apache only has certain permissions. Create the folder with the permissions on the server itself. If you chmod the entire folder, or try to use permissions from within PHP, you are creating security risks.

Comment: Does whatevever directory `dirname(__FILE__)` produces have the proper permissions for apache to create a new subdir within?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [is_writable()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-writable.php) function to check before if the parent directory is writable